# R: local Moran's I produces negative variance (localmoran)

Tags: r, local, spatial

I have to compute the local moran test statistics for a set of spatial data. I am using the R function localmoran from the spdep package. For some of my geographical units the variance of the local moran test statistics is NEGATIVE. This impedes me to plot e.g. LISA maps, for it makes it impossible to compute the significance of the local moran test for each unit.

Note that for the majority of the units the computation works fine! So I wouldn't ascribe the error to the function, the weights matrix is also correct, can it just be that some of the data is not compatible to the localmoran function??

Any idea how can this be possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that Moran's I is actually a "variance"? I thought it was the autocorrelation and that could be negative. You should post some code (with `library()` calls to load all needed packages). At the moment this isn't really a coding question, but rather about statistics.

Comment: it would be helpful if you provided a reproducible example. In any case, you might wanna take a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37664728/create-a-map-of-spatial-clusters-lisa-in-r)